# Proper Way to Use Cron Jobs

Tags: php, mysql, database, cron

I am currently developing a website that has to perform a task every 10 seconds. The website checks a database every ten seconds, finds rows that are to be processed, and then run a short script on each row.

The service is working great right now, but I just want to make sure that once the database gets very large, the service will still work efficiently.

I am using a cron job that runs every minute, with sleep functions every 10 seconds.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: So... What is your question?

Comment: How much data are we talking about here?  10s is too short if you're script is not fast and optimized.  I suggest that you look into DB triggers.

Comment: How does the function know that it should die after a certain amount of time has elapsed? Did you hard code in a certain number of iterations? Is it possible that the code can be running twice, at around the 60 second mark because two processes are running simultaneously?

Comment: Obviously I'm not familiar with your application, but querying the database every 10 seconds seems very excessive. Why so often? Why wouldn't 60 seconds or 5 minutes be more reasonable? Does the change in the db really need to be picked up that quickly? What happens when your script notices a change? Does that code fire another function that does more intensive work?

Comment: well database entries must be accurate to 10 seconds...if i run it every minute, then an entry that is supposed to delete in 20 seconds, will really delete in one minute

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure your tasks don't overlap, i.e. wait till the previous task is over before launching a new one. Otherwise, if your tasks take more than a minute (or whatever timer you've set for them), you'll end up with tons of those running in parallel and your system will run out of available resources.

Comment: And how do you suggest waiting? All i have is a cron job thats running a PHP file. Would the wait be something in the PHP or the cron job itself?

Comment: @user3647894 you might be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10552016/how-to-prevent-the-cron-job-execution-if-it-is-already-running